# How to print this number pattern in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print this pattern:

```
         1
        121
       12321
      1234321
     123454321
    12345654321
   1234567654321
  123456787654321
 12345678987654321
12345678910987654321
```

My program for this:

```
n=11
for i in range(1,n):
    for j in range(1,n-i):
        print(end=' ')
    for j in range(1,i+1):
        print(j,end='')
    for j in range(1,i-1):
        print(j,end='')
    print()
```

But this program is not printing the desired pattern. Instead it is printing:

```
         1
        12
       1231
      123412
     12345123
    1234561234
   123456712345
  12345678123456
 1234567891234567
1234567891012345678
```

Where am I going wrong?
Please do help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: "But this program is not printing the desired pattern"—what _is_ it printing? Please read [ask].

Comment: In your final `for` loop. To reverse the order `range` iterates, you'll need to use the 3rd "step" parameter for `range`. The arguments for `range` are `start` where it should start, `stop` where the iteration should stop, and `step`, the amount you should iterate on each step. Since you count up to `i` on your previous for loop, you'll probably want to start at 1 less than that. I'll let you figure out where to stop and the amount to step by.

Comment: Thanks got it:). I changed the last for loop  to ```for j in range(i-1,0,-1):```

Comment: Change the 2nd for loop as for j in range(n,i,-1):